# ExecuteCompleted of AdoConnection is not fired if user changes data via dbgrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, ado

if i execute a query like

```
Update Table Set aField = 1 Where tablePk = 1
```

i can get the affected record count (RecordsAffected parameter) from ExecuteComplete event of AdoConneciton. But if i change data via dbgrid, the ExecuteComplete event is not fired.

How can i get affected record count after insert/update/delete command that was executed by dbgrid?

Comment: Use the `AfterPost` event of the ADOQuery or ADOTable that is attached to the DBGrid. There will only be a single record updated, so you know the count ahead of time.

Comment: @KenWhite, the project contains about 100 adoquery that attached to dbGrids. i wanted to do it using connection but it seams it is impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to get the count of Rows Affected when you do updates,
inserts and deletes via a TDBgrid or other DB-aware components like TDBNavigator.  The reason is that DB-aware controls call the Post and Delete methods of TDataSet, and those calls overrides of InternalPost and InternalDelete in TAdoCustomDataSet.  They work in a fundamentally different way than executing a SQL statement via the ExecSql method of, say, TAdoQuery.

By design, TDataSet.Post and TDataSet.Delete should only affect a single row, so if the operation succeeds, you know that exactly one row was affected.

It's worth noting, though not much help for what you want to do, that there **is** a way to attach the same event handler to a number
of TAdoCustomDataSet descendants that share a TAdoConnection, as shown in this code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to AdoConnection1.DataSetCount - 1 do
    AdoConnection1.DataSets[i].AfterPost := AfterPost;
  AdoQuery1.Open;
  AdoQuery2.Open;
end;

procedure TForm1.AfterPost(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
  Q : TAdoQuery;
begin
  if DataSet is TAdoQuery then begin
    Q := TAdoQuery(DataSet);
    Caption := IntToStr(Q.RowsAffected);
  end
  else
    Caption := 'Post';
end;
```

Of course, if the datasets involved already have their own event handlers,
you would need some structure to store the existing handlers and chain to
the right one of them in the shared handler (f.i. TForm1.AfterPost above).

If you try the above code and observe what happens when you post an edit
from the DBGrid which is getting its data from a TAdoQuery, you'll see that unfortunately, the RowsAffected is zero.
That's because the TAdoQuery's FRowsAffected is only updated when its
`ExecSql` method is called, and it doesn't get called for dataset operations
invoked via the DBGrid.  The difference is because the AdoConnection's
`OnExecuteComplete` is called from the `Command` object used to carry out
TAdoQuery's `ExecSql`.  Operations initiated from the DBGrid, otoh, call
methods of the `RecordSet` object associated with the TAdoCustomDataSet in its InternalPost and InternalDelete,
and that does not invoke the AdoConnection's `OnExecuteComplete`.

The `RecordSet` objects have their own sets of events, see f.i. `RecordSetEvents`
in ADOInt.Pas, and conceivably you could set up shared event handlers for
those in a similar way to the shared `AfterPost` event example above.  However,
I don't think that that would do anything useful for you if you want to get
the RowsAffected value for a TDataset Insert/Update/Delete invoked from the
DBGrid (or, say a TDBNavigator connected to its TDataSource).

The reason I say that is that if you take a look at the source code for the
`InternalPost` method of the `TAdoCustomDataSet` you'll see that it includes

```
  if State = dsEdit then
    UpdateData
  else
  begin
    Recordset.AddNew(EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
    try
      UpdateData;
    except
```

and the nested `UpdateData` does its stuff by calling

```
    Recordset.Update(EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
```

Now, if you look at the MS Documentation for RecordSet.Update, you'll see e.g.

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecc2bf09.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

which clearly states that if `Update` does not affect exactly one record, an
exception is raised.  I imagine that's what @KenWhite had in mind when he said
"There will only be a single record updated".  So if RecordSet.Update succeeds,
you know that only one row was affected.

I haven't checked, but since `TAdoCustomDataSet.InternalDelete` uses its `Recordset`
object to do the deletion, similar would likely be true of that.

Comment: thanks for very well explained answer. i'll check what can be done in project by knowing update/insert/edit executed but not knowing RowsAffected.